# CKEditor not working in several browsers

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, opencart

I'm using the GitHub release of OpenCart (https://github.com/opencart/opencart) and in the admin panel, I can't get text to show up. The problem is cross-browser, though inconsistent:

- IE11 (currently up to date): Nothing happens
- Chrome 37.0.2062.124 m (currently up to date): My options (bold, italic and underline) toggle on every key press

Any clues, similar ideas, etc.?

---

#### Edit:

GitHub bug link:
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/1934

Comment: Sounds like an opencart bug to me, maybe add as an issue there? Do you get any console errors? It could be a configuration/dependancy/URL issue that is not a core bug per se.

Comment: @Nenotlep will open bug, no errors anywhere (on screen, console, etc.)

Comment: replace ckEditer with tnymce, it will help. ckEditer has lots of bugs.

Comment: I have faced this problem lots of time, so i have change the editer to tiny mnc. it's far better than ckEditer